# CAS bundle (an Elsevier document class) - pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable fonts

Tags: errors, captions, microtype, els-cas

I'm writing a scientific article using CAS bundle from Elsevier, which is a double-column format.

This how my document looks.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{notoccite} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\section{chapter1}
   ........  my text
\section{chapter2}
   ........  my text
\begin{figure}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig1.jpg}
   \label{fig1}
   \caption{This is my problem area, can't have long text}
\end{figure}
   ........ my text
\end{document}
```

The issue that I'm facing is a little strange because when the caption length of the figure exceeds one line, it throws me this `pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable fonts`.

[image]

However, I found that removing the `microtype` package allows me to have a long caption without any errors but the alignment in the rest of the document gets messed up. Based on the answers from previous posts related to this error, I tried to use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, `\usepackage{lmodern}`, and several options in microtype package (like `protrusion`, `expansion`, and `final`). None of these helps to fix my problem.

I need to have a long figure caption while maintaining the alignment of the rest of my document. I'd really appreciate if someone could help me figure this out.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make a compilable example, starting at the `\documentclass` line, and including a sample image with a caption that throws the error you mention.

Comment: Remove microtype but keep the long caption, compile. At the end of the log there should be a list of fonts (ending with pfb or pk). Show this list.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Please find the list below
fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/dpi600\ecss0900.pk> fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/dpi600\ecsx0900.pk>
fonts/enc/dvips/inconsolata/i4-t1-0.enc}
fonts/enc/dvips/stix/stix-t1.enc}
fonts/type1/public/inconsolata/Inconsolata-zi4r.pfb> fonts/type1/public/stix/STIXGeneral-Bold.pfb>
fonts/type1/public/stix/STIXGeneral-Italic.pfb
fonts/type1/public/stix/STIXGeneral-Regular.pfb>
fonts/type1/public/stix/stix-mathit.pfb>
fonts/type1/public/stix/stix-mathrm.pfb>

Comment: Install the cm-super package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MWE you provide does not compile for me.  When I create my own `fig1.jpg` (Should this really be a JPEG?) and change `linewidth` to `\linewidth`, I cannot reproduce the bug with TeX Live 2019.

The version of `cas-dc.cls` I have (2.1) loads `stix` as the math font and `charis` as the text font, which should both be scalable and work properly.  If it can’t find `charis`, it loads `stix` as the text font too.  It also looks for `inconsolata` as the fixed-width font, although that should not be causing the problem you have.  You should make sure these packages are up-to-date.  Are you getting warnings in your log file about them being missing?

If you are loading `stix` through your class file, it should not be necessary to also load either `bm` or `amssymb`, although neither will hurt.

PS

The actual document, unlike the MWE, was using a sans-serif font, and the class file does not load one. Loading any T1 sans-serif font would work.

Comment: When I use without \usepackage{microtype}, this is how my log file looks. And it continues till the end and generates pdf without any issues.

LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+cmss on input line 97.
("C:\Users\Sid\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\t1cmss.fd"
File: t1cmss.fd 2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
<pflow.jpg, id=25, 851.3406pt x 436.5108pt>
File: pflow.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)
<use pflow.jpg>
Package pdftex.def Info: pflow.jpg  used on input line 98.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 238.25444pt x 122.16223pt.

Comment: Whereas with \usepackage{microtype} this is what I get

Package microtype Info: Loading generic protrusion settings for font family
(microtype)             `cmss' (encoding: T1).
(microtype)             For optimal results, create family-specific settings.
(microtype)             See the microtype manual for details.
<pflow.jpg, id=25, 851.3406pt x 436.5108pt>
File: pflow.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)
<use pflow.jpg>
Package pdftex.def Info: pflow.jpg  used on input line 98.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 238.25444pt x 122.16223pt.

Continued ......

Comment: [1{C:/Users/Sid/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}
! pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable 
fonts.
\AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox 
                                                  \fi \fi 
l.104 
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Comment: @Sid Hmmm. The `cmss` sounds like it’s trying to load a sans-serif from being, which the class file does not set. The example you gave does not do that. You might load a sans-serif font, such as `\usepackage{DejaVuSans}`. But please post a NWE that reproduces your bug.

Comment: adding the \usepackage{DejaVuSans} worked. I really appreciate your help. Thanks.